# ag grid sizeColumnsToFit for columns not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

I have used ag-grid ng2 and trying to apply sizeColumnsToFit.
For example: If there are 4 columns then it should be automatically resized and fit to the width of grid.
gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit() not working.

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    enableColResize: true
};
 
this.columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Age", field: "age", width: 90, minWidth: 50, maxWidth: 100},
    {headerName: "Country", field: "country", width: 120},
    {headerName: "Year", field: "year", width: 90},
    {headerName: "Date", field: "date", width: 110}
];
    
gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
```

Comment: Can you please share your code? Need to see how you have implemented so far....

Answer (score 17):

Try this code.. while defining columnDefs set suppressSizeToFit: false for all fields,

```
this.columnDefs = [
 {headerName: "Age", field: "age", width: 90, minWidth: 50, maxWidth: 100,suppressSizeToFit: false},
 {headerName: "Country", field: "country", width: 120,suppressSizeToFit: false},
 {headerName: "Year", field: "year", width: 90,suppressSizeToFit: false},
 {headerName: "Date", field: "date", width: 110,suppressSizeToFit: false}
 ];
```

Then in onGridReady use the below code.

```
onGridReady(params) {
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;   
params.api.sizeColumnsToFit(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi @TutorBoys: did you guys figure the solution to it?

Comment: This worked for me. I just added it to `defaultColDef`.

Answer (score 5):

Resizing Columns When Data Is Renderered
There are two scenarios main where scenarios where you might want to resize columns based on grid data:

1. Row Data is available at grid initialisation
2. Row Data is available after grid initialisation, typically after data has been set asynchronously via a server call

In the first case you can fire autoSizeColumns() in either the gridReady or the firstDataRendered event as the row data will have been rendered by the time the grid is ready.

**In the second case however you can only reliably use firstDataRendered as the row data will be made available, and hence rendered, after the grid is ready.**

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: For me onRowDataUpdated event worked to resize the columns to full width.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the width of the container containing AgGrid anything less than 100% did the trick for me.

Comment: I can't believe that worked. I added width 99.9% and the scrollbar is gone. Strange

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide `columnApi.autoSizeColumns()` with a list of all column IDs like this:

```
function onFirstDataRendered (params) {
  params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    const colIds = params.columnApi.getAllColumns().map(c => c.colId)
    params.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(colIds)
  }, 50)
}

…

<AgGridReact onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered} … />
…
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a reusable ag-grid react wrapper component that will resize its columns to fit its container's width automatically. It watches its container's width and listens to `window.resize` event, then it calls `gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit()` in `useEffect` when required. If interested, read the code in steps [here](https://rexebin.medium.com/build-an-ag-grid-react-component-that-auto-resize-columns-to-fit-container-width-4fca3f9fb1c4), or see all in a working sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggridautoresizetofitcontainer-dn6wi) at CodeSandBox.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { FirstDataRenderedEvent } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
 public onFirstDataRedndered(event: FirstDataRenderedEvent){
    event.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
 }
```